# Python - Many methods with small differences

Tags: python, performance, syntactic-sugar, code-readability

I have several methods that vary little in construction. They are for setting the (linux-like) permissions on a given item (field_name). The variables `oview_perms`, `gview_perms`, `aview_perms` represent Owner, Group, and Anonymous permissions respectively. These variables are immutables, so that's why I set them on return.

Perhaps there is a way to simplify this, yet still keep it easily readable?

```
def set_oview_perm(self, field_name, perm):
    self.oview_perms = self._set_field_permission(self.oview_perms, field_name, perm)

def set_gview_perm(self, field_name, perm):
    self.gview_perms = self._set_field_permission(self.gview_perms, field_name, perm)

def set_aview_perm(self, field_name, perm):
    self.aview_perms = self._set_field_permission(self.aview_perms, field_name, perm)

def set_oedit_perm(self, field_name, perm):
    self.oedit_perms = self._set_field_permission(self.oedit_perms, field_name, perm)

def set_gedit_perm(self, field_name, perm):
    self.gedit_perms = self._set_field_permission(self.gedit_perms, field_name, perm)

def set_aedit_perm(self, field_name, perm):
    self.aedit_perms = self._set_field_permission(self.aedit_perms, field_name, perm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def set_perm(self, ptype, field_name, perm):
    setattr(self, ptype + '_perm', self._set_field_permission(getattr(self, ptype + '_perm'), field_name, perm))
```

where `ptype` is `'gedit'`, `'oview'` etc. I haven't tried, but this should work.